# How to pull a method out of its class (and into a new or existing)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper, refactoring

What is the easiest way of pulling an existing method out of its class and into a new class using Visual studio 2010 / Resharper?

Edit: I use Resharper version 5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with

public void Method() {}

1. First, make the method static using the "Make Method Static" command.

   public static void Method(){}
2. Then, add a local variable of the type of the new class:

   public static void Method(){Class2 me = new Class2();}
3. Then, use Introduce Parameter

   public static void Method(Class2 me) {}
4. Then use "Make Method non-Static". In class2:

   public void Method(){}

Comment: I fail to see the <move method> step, is it implicit?
I also fail to see the gain of the variable => parameter step.

Comment: The method moves when you (1) add the parameter and then (2) make the method non-static, which turns the parameter into the "this" pointer, which makes the method an instance method of that class.

Comment: After trying both methods some I reallocted the check to this answer.

Comment: I switch place one step 1 and 2. 
Find it less cumbersome when Class2 takes arguments in the constructor that I have as fields in Class1.

Answer (score 4):

Same as above, but I would not do the conversion to static-method manually. Pull up the "Refactor this" menu (using shortcuts of course, ctrl+shift+R), then select "Make method static", then "Refactor this"->"Move".

Note:

If you're talking about moving a method in a class hierarchy, you can use "Push members down" or "Pull members up"

Comment: I didn't mean you should make the method static manually. I meant "Make Method Static". Also, doing a "Move" next will leave the method static, and it wasn't static before.

Answer (score 1):

In up-to-date Resharper, there's Move Refactoring. You either press F6 while the cursor is in method signature, or cut-paste code to the new location, and Resharper offers you to apply the refactoring.