# How can I update the references of a property that has been moved inside of an object

Tags: c#, .net

How can I update all the references of a property so that it looks into a new object before pulling the property instead? I tried googling for answers and didn't find much. So I'm posting to see if the community knows of an easy way to solve this or if it's even possible. If I can't do this easily I'll just find all references and go down the list until all the references have been updated. There are way more properties in this class which is why I'm trying to find an easy solution.

I have this

```
Structure{
    public int OrganizationID; 100+ References
}
```

I need this

```
Structure{
    public OrganizationInformation OrganizationInformation;
}

OrganizationInformation{
    public int OrganizationId;
}
```

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756280/how-to-pull-a-method-out-of-its-class-and-into-a-new-or-existing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do this without add-ons, so if you're worried about name collisions when just trying to do a find and replace, you could;

1. Hit <kbd>F2</kbd> (Rename) on `OrganizationID` and rename it to something like `MYUNIQUENAMEOrganizationId` or similar which will update the references
2. Extract to your new class as per your post
3. Find and replace `MYUNIQUENAMEOrganizationId` with `OrganizationInformation.OrganizationId`